# Fail/terminate node.js process if Mithril Ospec tests fail

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mithril.js

When I run unit tests via [Ospec](https://github.com/MithrilJS/mithril.js/tree/master/ospec) for Mithril, I can see if tests fail locally in the console.

What I'm looking for is a solution that will not allow a following Node.js build script to execute if one or more of the tests fail.

I don't want code to be pushed up to another environment/lane if the unit tests aren't passing.

I don't see how to accomplish this in the docs.

In Node, I'm running `ospec && someBuildProcess`.

The answer might be a Node.js thing, but I'm at a loss for what to look for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ospec calls `process.exit(1)` if any tests fail, and the command string you posted should work. I just verified it locally with the following setup:

https://gist.github.com/tivac/d90c07592e70395639c63dd5100b50a6

ospec runs, fails, and the `echo` command never gets called.

Can you post some more details about your setup?

Comment: I think my mind-map was overloaded yesterday; because your exactly right, and my code already fails like it should.  I woke this morning, saw your post, and wondered how all the build processes in my head got mixed together yesterday. Cheers.